# ¿Cómo puedo convertir un rango a lista en elixir?

Tags: lista, elixir

Si defino un rango como el siguiente,

```
rango = 1..5
```

¿Hay una manera de convertirlo a lista?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Creo que [esto](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#to_list/1) es lo que usted esta buscando

**to_list (colección)**

***Convierte la colección a una lista***

```
iex> Enum.to_list 1..5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

espero le ayude